# Rules for selecting a word in a Windows RichEdit20W control

Tags: mfc, richedit-control

In a MFC application I have an `.rc` file with this content:

```
IDD_PROP_TEXT DIALOGEX 0, 0, 210, 164
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_CHILD
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif", 400, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_EDIT,"RichEdit20W",ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP,1,3,207,158
END
```

When I double click on a string like `first_second` in the Rich Edit control I get selected just the first part before the `_` or the second part after the `_` or just the `_`, depending on where I double click.

In the following screenshot I just double clicked on a character in `second`.

[image]

I would like to change this behavior and `_` should not be treated as a breaking character.

How can I do that?

I have found `ECO_AUTOWORDSELECTION` at [CRichEditCtrl::SetOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20z1432s.aspx) but it does not explain the word breaking rules...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [EM_SETWORDBREAKPROCEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/Controls/em-setwordbreakprocex).

With your own [EditWordBreakProcEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Richedit/nc-richedit-editwordbreakprocex) it should be possible to define your own rules.

The flag `ECO_AUTOWORDSELECTION` just sets the feature that a double click selects a word.

I am not sure that this applies to this case too, but reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/use-word-and-line-break-information) seam to point to my supposed answer.

Comment: thank you, I'll give it a try. It seems to me that I have to use  `EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC` and `EditWordBreakProc` (instead of the `EX` version) since I have Riche Edit 2.0.

Comment: I have found an interesting example here https://github.com/petterh/textedit/blob/v2.5.1003.0/EditWordBreakProc.cpp courtesy of Petter Hesselberg https://stackoverflow.com/users/3968276/petter-hesselberg?tab=profile